# How to return to first keyframe after parent and unparent

Tags: constraints, parent

I'm new here and first sorry for my english. So, I'm trying to create an animation of reloading a revolver, that is, I put the cartridge child of the cylinder and after being ejected I wanted the cartridge to become a child of the hand and after hand insert the cartridge into the cylinder i try to make it go back to being a child of the cylinder going back to the same position inside the cylinder as in the initial keyframe. I can't get the last part to work it's always slightly different from the starting position and when I get it to work the cartridge goes out of place at the beginning of the animation. How do I make it work properly? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: did you try just to copy the keyframe from the start position to the end position? if this doesn't help, please provide a simplified blend file so we can check it out. Thanks. And by the way: your english is really good - i couldn't recognize that you aren't a native english speaker...

Comment: Thanks, yes I already tried that the animation is messed up

Comment: just to make sure i understood your right: problem is between frame 51 and 57 where the bullet should move with chamber:1? is that correct? (objection hearsay...sorry, watched too much Depp/Heard.... :D)

Comment: The problem starts from keyframe 170 I normally try to put the cartridge as child of the hand until keyframe 220 which is when the hand touches the cylinder, from there I try to put the cartridge as child of the cylinder again (and set influence to 0 on hand bone) and as the end of the animation needs be equal to the start, the cartridge needs to be in the same position inside the cylinder as the first keyframe.

Comment: it is just confusing to me that  - as you send the file now, at 170 it looks like this : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxvQ1.png so i hoped the starting position would be right, because you said you had problems to get the come back to the first position again

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Blender. Here I think this file is the closest to what I want to exemplify.
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=vBWX0mEz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/vBWX0mEz/) I wanted between frame 170 and 220 the cartridge would follow the hand. And between frame 0 to 170 the cartridge follows the cylinder.

Comment: well, if you made this all on your own (and it wasn't copied from somewhere) you are for sure not new to Blender... ;)

Comment: I'm a newbie, I started using it about 2 months ago. I played with influence in 2 other projects but nothing like this.

Comment: is there a reason why your bullet bones are not at the same position as your bullets? normally the positions should be the same...

Comment: No, it was just a placement error by whoever created the model. it's a little annoying to move it around, but that's what I got for now.

Comment: i would first correct that tbh. Because if you rig a mesh with wrong positions, of course the whole rig will mess up the animation. just a small example: if you rotate around a point with just a bit of offset, the rotation will look totally different, right? and that's what will happen to your rig too. and of course then the child of constraint result will look different too....

Comment: Okay, I'll talk to the creator to fix this. Is this affecting the issues of influences?

Comment: of course. Just make a new blend file, add an armature with two bones. Parent the cube to the last bone. Move the bone in pose mode. See how it rotates? Now go in edit mode and move the the cube to another place. Rotate the bone again -> different result -> or move the cube in object mode -> different result again, so yes, the position is important.